# Grab title from website, decode HTML entities

Tags: php

I'm incredibly close to giving up on this one. From what I have seen, this should be easy, but nothing I try is close to the correct result.

I'm grabbing the title from a website, and I want to make sure that all HTML entities are converted back to the correct character.

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.metacafe.com/watch/10859663/samsung_galaxy_products_rettingers_rants_technobuffalo/');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$urlTitle = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$urlTitle = html_entity_decode($urlTitle, ENT_QUOTES);
```

The output of the above is:

```
Samsung Galaxy Products - Rettinger&#039;s Rants - TechnoBuffalo - Video
```

The code example above is actually just a subset of things I have tried to get this to work (including forcing the UTF-8 charset  on html_entity_decode which shouldn't be necessary as I'm using PHP 5.4 and that should be default anyway). I've seen lots of hints and tips, none of them seem to make a difference.

If any one has a new example will work I'd be greatly appreciative.

Many thanks

Comment: I just tried your code snippet on my web server and it works fine. Perhaps something to do with default encoding? Try `$urlTitle = html_entity_decode($urlTitle, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`. Can you edit your question with the result of this?

Comment: strange!!! I get clean title even before `html_entity_decode`

Comment: i think you require [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) to decode `&#039;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I feel a little bit stupid.

Turns out the title was being appropriately decoded, but elsewhere in my view class that output was being escaped again with htmlspecialchars...

However, I think it only right to at least share the completed code. I had simplified it earlier. This is the actual code making use of Zend Framework:

```
$html = $request->getBody();

$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);

$urlTitle = $dom->query('title');
if ($urlTitle->count())
{
    $urlTitle = $urlTitle->current()->nodeValue;
    $urlTitle = html_entity_decode($urlTitle, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $urlTitle = htmlspecialchars_decode($urlTitle, ENT_QUOTES);
}
else
{
    $urlTitle = '';
}

$urlDescription = $dom->query("meta[name='description']");
if ($urlDescription->count())
{
    $urlDescription = $urlDescription->current()->getAttribute('content');
    $urlDescription = html_entity_decode($urlDescription, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $urlDescription = htmlspecialchars_decode($urlDescription, ENT_QUOTES);
}
else
{
    $urlDescription = '';
}

return array($urlTitle, $urlDescription);
```

I have since found some examples that DO need to be decoded and the above code does them correctly. The above code also includes the correct query to get the meta description from the page too.

Thank you to everyone who took the time to comment and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would go and just change all the characters back to normal manually using

```
str_replace();
```

https://www.php.net/str_replace